# Reading registry

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I have written the following code:

```
RegistryKey _Key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("SystemFileAssociations", true);
foreach (String s in names)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Done.===================" + s);
}
_Key.Close();
```

**prints an entry that is equal to `.txt`**

However, when I do this, i.e. try to access the `/HKCR/SFA/.txt` key like this:

```
RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("SystemFileAssociations//.txt", true);
rootKey.Close();
```

I get the following error:

`SystemNullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown because the `rootKey` is null (OpenSubKey operation failed because `//` instead of `\\` is used in key name).
Use the following code:

```
using(RegistryKey rootKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("SystemFileAssociations\\.txt", true)) {
    if(rootKey != null) { 
        // do staff
    }
}
```

Comment: rootKey is not actually null. I can see a .txt entry both at the registry as well as via the other code segment that I have posted

Comment: @user2053912 rootkey *variable* is null in your code fragment(the exception confirms that). please, check my code again - your key name is wrong

Comment: Terribly sorry. Thanks for being polite.

Comment: @user2053912 Never mind... happy coding)) and I believe you can accept the correct answer